# Creating File Directory from Worksheets Information

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, range

I am trying to make a script to automatically create a file directory from information on forms I have created in excel.

**What the file structure will look like**
[image: What the file structure will look like]

**What the form looks like**
[image: What the form looks like]

I have a script that will create the file directory after i extract the information. I just need help with the script that will extract the information and copy it to column A on my File Directory sheet. A9 of the form will always be the name of the folder and sub folders will either be product data, shop drawings, samples, warranties, or material certificates. not all forms will have all of them though.

My thought would be to use a if function if the sheet has product data it would place A9/productdata to file directory. I need it to do this for each sheet in the workbook.

```
Sub FileDirectory()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "File Directory" Then
            ws.Range("A9").Copy Sheets("File Directory").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is as far as i got to copy A9 from each worksheet to file directory. i cant figure out how to create the if to create the sub folders. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the subfolder names are unique, perhaps you could use the `Range.Find` method to see if they are present and, if so, concatenate with the main folder name.  Or, if they are always in the same cell, check that cell.

Comment: Not sure if I understand but from https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI2i6.png
you want folders 09 24 00 PORTLAND CEMENT PLASTER, 09 24 00 PORTLAND CEMENT PLASTER\PRODUCT DATA, 09 24 00 PORTLAND CEMENT PLASTER\SAMPLES, 09 24 00 PORTLAND CEMENT PLASTER\MATERIAL CERTIFICATES and 09 24 00 PORTLAND CEMENT PLASTER\INSTRUCTIONS TO SUBMIT. Is that correct?

Comment: The subfolder names will be product data, samples, shop drawings, or material certificates. But not all forms will use each sub folder. The parent folder name will always be in cell A9. I will have a workbook with all of the forms in it. I need the script to start with the first page and copy the A9 for that sheet into my file directory sheet. Then check for which sub folders it will use on that sheet and put the parent folder name / sub folder name after it like the picture then goto the next sheet.

Comment: You are an expert on your subject. Please accept that others are not. Apart from A9, HOW can we deduct what subfolders need to be created?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm trying to explain in a way that makes sense so every form will be the same except the name in A9 will be different and they might not use each section. The sections are separated by the Gray headers. There are only 5 options for headers that will be in column B either product data, samples, shop drawings, material data or warranties. For example this form uses product data, samples, and material certificates. I need to make a script that will search each form which will be it's own sheet and paste the information in column A of my file directory sheet.

Comment: So it would first copy A9 of this form and paste it into A1 of file directory then search the form to see which of the 5 headings are used. If it finds the heading it will paste A9/Heading into A2 of file directories sheet. For example 092400 Portland cement plaster/product data would be put in cell A2 of file directory sheet then 092400 Portland cement plaster/samples would be put in A3 of file directories. Then after its done with that form it would move to the next form which would be the next sheet until it finishes the workbook.

Comment: Then I have a script that will create a folder directory based on the information in column A of file directory. The code I posted copies A9 to my file directory sheet. I need help with creating code to search column B for each heading and if its used paste it in file directory with A9/Heading format.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work for you provided the subfolder names are in column A.

```
Sub FileDirectory()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim subfolders() As String
Dim cell As Range, i As Integer

subfolders = Split("PRODUCT DATA,SAMPLES,SHOP DRAWINGS,MATERIAL CERTIFICATES", ",")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "File Directory" Then
        ws.Range("A9").Copy Sheets("File Directory").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A:A") 'Changing this cell range to a smaller, defined range will improve performance
            For i = LBound(subfolders) To UBound(subfolders)
                If cell.Value = subfolders(i) Then
                    Sheets("File Directory").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Range("A9").Value + "/" + cell.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next cell
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm! This will save me so much time at work.